# Current MySQL IN statement strings Cats as an "OR" - Need it as an "And" statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following complex SQL statement that uses an "IN" to search for multiple categories.

```
SELECT MATCH(placename,fullloc) AGAINST ('' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as score, places.PlaceName, places.fullloc, places.PlaceID, places.ImageThumb, places.contributorid, places.verified, places.verified_by, places.verified_date, places.visibility 
FROM places 
INNER JOIN places_cats ON places.PlaceID = places_cats.PlaceID 
WHERE STATUS IN (1,0) 
  AND places_cats.CATID in (129,75,104) 
  AND (visibility = 1 OR (visibility in (2,3) 
  AND places.contributorid = '999999999'))
GROUP BY PlaceID 
ORDER BY score DESC
```

I want to be able to toggle this from an "IN" which basically makes it a multiple "OR" statement to something that will give me a multiple "AND" statement.  Is there a SIMPLE SQL command that will let me do this, or do I have to actually create a multiple "AND" statement?

The CATID list can become quite long.  In fact, sometime the cat list is 35 items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IN` compares one value in one row against a list.  What you're asking for is *completely different*: to find whether a separate row exists for each value in the list.  You can't do that with a simple operator.  (If you truly had an `AND`, you'd get no rows back, because the same value can't equal both 129 and 75.)

You have to either join once or subquery once for every category you want.

```
SELECT ...
FROM places
INNER JOIN places_cats pc1 ON places.PlaceID = pc1.PlaceID AND pc1.CATID = 129
INNER JOIN places_cats pc2 ON places.PlaceID = pc2.PlaceID AND pc2.CATID = 75
INNER JOIN places_cats pc3 ON places.PlaceID = pc3.PlaceID AND pc3.CATID = 104
```

Or:

```
SELECT ...
FROM places
WHERE places.PlaceID IN (SELECT PlaceID FROM places_cats WHERE CATID = 129)
AND places.PlaceID IN (SELECT PlaceID FROM places_cats WHERE CATID = 75)
AND places.PlaceID IN (SELECT PlaceID FROM places_cats WHERE CATID = 104)
```

Or:

```
SELECT ...
FROM places
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM places_cats WHERE places_cats.PlaceID = places.PlaceID AND CATID = 129)
AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM places_cats WHERE places_cats.PlaceID = places.PlaceID AND CATID = 75)
AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM places_cats WHERE places_cats.PlaceID = places.PlaceID AND CATID = 194)
```

Which one is easier for you to generate (and runs most efficiently) depends on your code and MySQL's idiosyncrasies.

Comment: I think I need to come up with a better overall strategy for querying the database.  I see another StackOverFlow question in my future.  Thanks!